# Can't align transformation to 3d cursor

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-cursor

community!

I do have a problem here. I have a project and I want to align an object with a 3d-cursor.
But whenever I choose an object, it's rotating within its own location.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use 3D cursor as center of rotation, use the *Pivot Point* menu.
(You changed *Transform orientation* in your screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Gorgeous! Thank you for your help!